# Name of font used in Google Plus iOS App?

Tags: ios, google-plus

Does anyone know the name of the font used in the Google Plus iOS app?
If I wanted to use the same font within my app, how would I go about it?

Comment: Do you mind sharing the font as an answer to further help the community? :)

Comment: Helvetica-Light was close enough for me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a screenshot. Cut out a text area and use [this](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) site. It will detect it for you.

Comment: that got me close enough.. thanks ;)